# Regarding Automation Approach

Tags: automated-tests, powerbuilder

I am supposed to automate an application which is developed in PowerBuilder. In order to test this Application we are using Rational Robot as a functional testing tool. We expect at least 40 -50% of change control in the Application for each release. Release trends are scheduled at least 3 times in a year.

The product has different setup for each client. Accordingly scenario has been derived. Although if is there any change occurs, it would  be in functional feature and also in interface. Pointing to that, need to proceed with automation. Identified few areas which are stabilized (i.e., where no major changes occurs) to automate. Will that be feasible for proceeding with Automation?

Could you please suggest me how to go about on this?

Comment: What kinds of things are different for each client? If objects are keeping the same name and just moving around Robot can deal with that. I know it's not what you want to hear, but you need to test the parts the developers are changing.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the answer to your last question involve a consultant spending two days interviewing the development team, then three days developing a report. And, in some cases, I'd say the report was preliminary, introductory, and rushed. However, let me throw out a few ideas that may help manage expectations on your team.

Testing automation is great for checking for regressions in functionality that allegedly isn't being touched. Things like framework changes or database changes can cause untouched code to crash. For risk-averse environments (e.g. banking, pharmaceutical prescriptions), the investment in automation is well worth the effort.

However, what I've seen **often** is an underestimation of the effort. To really test all the functionality in a unit (let's say a window, for example), you need to review the specifications, design tests that test each functional point, plan your data (what is the data going into the window, how will you make sure this data is as expected when you start the test each time, what is the data when you've finished your tests, how will you ensure the data, including non-visible data, is correct), then script and debug all your tests. I'm not sure what professional testers say (I'm a developer by trade, but have taken a course in an automated testing tool), but if you aren't planning for the same amount of effort to be expended on developing the automation tests as you're spending on application development for the same functionality, I think you'll quickly become frustrated. Add to that the changing functionality means changing testing scripts, and automated testing can become a significant cost. (So, tell your manager that automated testing doesn't mean you push a button and things get tested. < grin > )

That's not to say that you can't expend less effort on testing and get *some* results, but you get what you pay for. Having a script that opens and closes all the windows in the app provides *some* value, but it won't tell you that a new behaviour implemented in the framework is being overridden on window X, or that a database change has screwed up the sequencing of items in a drop down DataWindow, or a report completion time goes from five seconds to five hours. However, again, don't underestimate the effort. This is a new tool with a new language and idiosyncrasies that need to be figured out and mastered.

Automated testing can be a great investment. If the cost of failure is significant, like a badly prescribed drug causing a death, then the investment is worth it. However, for cases where there is a high turn over of functionality (like I think you're describing) and the consequences of a failure is less critical, you might want to consider comparing the cost/benefit of testing automation with additional manual testing resources.

Good luck,

Terry

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to what @Terry said: It sounds like you are both new to automation in general and to Rational Robot in particular.

One thing to keep in mind is that test automation is software development and needs to be treated as such. That means you need personnel dedicated to the automation effort who are solid programmers and have expertise in the tool being used (Robot in this case).

If your team does not have the general programming/automation skills and the specific Robot skills, you are going to need to hire that personnel or get existing staff trained in those skill sets.

Comment: I'll second that. I was recently at a client who hired an end-user for testing. While he did great doing manual testing, he really had a lot of learning curves to overcome when they threw an automated test tool at him. Even developers struggled to help him because they were unfamiliar with the product. Both sides grew frustrated, and he chose to leave. Good point Tom E.